# Asynchronous calls in web development

Tags: java, php, asp.net, web

I have a very big misunderstanding regarding asynchronous calls and I couldn't find a reasonable answer to my question (I'm sorry if it's a stupid question but it seems that I can't understand this)

Is there any way in web development to call functions asynchronously without Javascript ?

When I mean asynchronous I refer to calling a function that does heavy processing to run in the background as the page loads and when it finishes to display results to the user without making him wait for the function to process (and display blank page).

Are sockets viable ?

Languages :  PHP , JAVA , ASP.NET , PYTHON

Thanks.

Comment: You could embed a Java applet or Flash or Silverlight into your page to achieve something similar, but the results wouldn't be as appealing as with JS IMHO.

Comment: For example if I want to call a php/java function to do the heavy work , I want to be able to render the whole page and when the function ends processing to display results to the user (in a div or span), or to display to the users the output as is created (like popen in php)

Comment: Why can't you use JS? Modern asynchronous web development _screams_ JS.

Comment: I will use JS but it's still dificult for me to realize that only Javascript can achieve something like this. And the realtime web is based on Javascript sockets (or websockets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is no reason for the server to wait until all dynamic content is available before sending data to the client. So it could send some data (e.g. a "please wait"-message), then do the heavy processing and then send the response, all as reply to one http-request. This means, however, that the browser will display a loading bar all the time until the final message has been received.

Comment: Yes , but noone want to see Loading for 5 - 8 seconds

Comment: I thought that maybe Java (servlets or JSP) could manipulate the DOM like Javascript because java is multithreading, parallel and can have asynchronous calls native. PHP is singlethread and at the moment it doesn't implement asynchronous calls

Comment: The problem is not the server side but on the client side. The browser cannot do asychronous calls to check if new content is available (or even open sockets for bidirectional communication) without using javascript or reloading the page (or a frame on the page)

Comment: So , to clear my mind, to achieve asynchronous in web development we have to call that functions (php or java or anyother web language) from Javascript via Ajax ?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers . Only one question : Can Ajax call a webservice (java or php but more java) that can do stuff concurent (in parallel - basically async for better performance) and send the result to ajax callback function to update the page ? Is this the way big web app are doing ? Thank you again

Comment: Well, basically you can start multithreaded programs on the server (php might indeed not be the right language for this). But remember that usual Ajax-Requests are always initiated by the client, so asyc calls in the manner of async webservices ("you call me back when you're ready") are not possible. If you want to establish a bidirectional connection between server and client that could be used by the server to push results to the client, you might want to take a look at websockets (However, browser support is an issue there).

Answer (score 1):

Not without ugly, 20th-century hacks such as constantly reloading the page every few seconds until the results are available.

Comment: So , without the use of Javascript there will be imposible to make web applications asynchronous ? (rendred the page first - display results as they are processed)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and comments you have posted. There are many ways to display data as it is rendered by the server. It all depends on how you structure your application. In retrospect, Javascript provides the most elegant solution.

One method, would be to use [Meta-Refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) tag to constantly refresh the page and display content as it becomes available.

Another method would be, to have iFrames within the webpage. The URL of the iFrame would a be page which does heavy processing. This way, the of the page would be loaded without waiting for the iFrame to be loaded.

Comment: Ooo, I forgot completly about iframes, because I don't use them anymore (since MVC frameworks). but my question is : Java knows how to call asynchronous tasks and do stuff in background and when result is available display it. Why is there a need for javascript (only because the browser is involved ) ?

Comment: You have to remember that HTTP is a stateless protocol, when you send a GET request to a URL, you get a response back. After that there is no way for the server to call you back and say, I have more information regarding your query. All these hacks, provide a way for the client to keep the connection to the server open, until the relevant response is available.

Answer (score 0):

When using my Android phone, often I receive pop-ups asking to close programs I don't even use, Facebook the moot common.  There are several.  I don't understand how they are running when I don't use them

Comment: many apps run in the background. They run so they can update information, or check on something. This is a very common occurrence.